# Prove that $f:(0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous iff $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

My professor provided a different, and less illuminating proof; but I wrote this one and would like to know if it's legitimate.

Let $f:(0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}~$  be uniformly continuous. $f$ is bounded on this domain. Thus choosing a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset [0, 1]$ such that for all $n, ~ x_{n+1} < x_n$, and $\{x_n\} \rightarrow 0$, $\{f(x_n)\}$ is also a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and thus contains a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$. Call its limit $L_1$.

Fix $\epsilon/2 >0$. There exists $N$ such that for any ${n_k}>N, ~|f(x_{n_k}) - L_1|<\epsilon/2$.

For the same $\epsilon$, the uniform continuity of $f$ furnishes a $\delta$ such that $|x-y|< \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon/2$.

Choose $M$ sufficiently large that for all $n, n_{k} < N, ~ |x_{n}-x_{n_k}|<\delta$ (this value is guaranteed to exist because all subsequences of $x_n$ approach arbitrarily close to $0$. Fix $P = \max(N, M)$.

Then, for all $n, n_k>P$

$|f(x_n) - L| \leq |f(x_n) - f(x_{n_k})| + |f(x_{n_k})-L_1| <\epsilon$.

**edits as per suggestion**

Choose another such sequence $\{x'_n\}$. All of the above statements hold true. For this sequence, $f(x'_n) \rightarrow L_2$

Now consider the sequence $X = \{x_1, x'_1, x_2, x_2'...\}$. This sequence also converges to $0$, and as such $f(X)$ is convergent, and has two convergent subsequences, which must converge to the same value: thus $L_1 = L_2$.

Thus the $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$ exists.

**End of edits**

The other direction I prove by defining an extension onto the compact domain $[0,1]$; my professor did it the same way so I'm less concerned.

For this one, what would be most helpful would be feedback on flow and notation if it's more or less correct, or suggestions about fixes if it isn't. Thanks.

Comment: You have two $L$ doing different jobs. You might wanna change that. Otherwise the proof looks fine.

Comment: Your proof is incomplete. You need to show that for **any** sequence $x_n \to 0$ that $f(x_n)$ has the same limit $L$. The above only shows it for one sequence.

Comment: You don't need the constraint $x_{n+1} < x_n$, if you remove this the proof still holds and the overall proof is correct.

Comment: @copper.hat Is the reason it makes the proof incorrect because it excludes certain sequences which converge to 0?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the restriction to show that a limit exists, But if you want to apply the same proof to an arbitrary sequence that converges to $0$ then you need to remove the restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer as such, just an alternative approach.

Often $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs obfuscate the salient points.

Note that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then it maps Cauchy sequences
into Cauchy sequences. This is the crucial element.

Pick a specific sequence that converges to $0$, say $x_n = {1 \over n}$, then since $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy we have $f(x_n) \to L$ for some $L$. This is our
candidate value for the limit.

Now suppose $x_n' \to 0$ for some other sequence. As above we have
$f(x_n') \to L'$ and we want to show that $L'=L$.

Now a little trick: Pick the sequence $x_1,x_1',....,x_n,x_n',...$.
Since the sequence converges to $0$ it is Cauchy and hence
$f(x_1),f(x_1'),....,f(x_n),f(x_n'),...$ is Cauchy and hence
converges. Since there are subsequences that converge to $L,L'$
we see that $L'=L$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What is the value of choosing two subsequences? Would it be sufficient to just note that $f(x_n) \rightarrow L$? Or are you choosing two to show that for *any* sequence that converges to $0$, $f(x_n)$ converges to the same value thus this must be the limit?                      2) Second question: Is my proof legit even if it is less illustrative of the important points than yours?

Comment: The first thing is to find a candidate limit $L$, which you have also done in your proof. The second thing is to show that for **any** other sequence (converging to $0$) that the mapped sequence also converges to the same $L$. Your proof needs to address the latter point.

Comment: Is it correct with the edits I made?

Comment: Almost, see my comment above.